# How to stop PlaySync() in SoundPlayer on button click in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, window, soundplayer

I have a window application that enables you to play sound based on the letter you click. You can repeat the sound based on the number you entered in the TextBox and you can play from 1 to 3 in a sequence. It is all working with the bellow code. but I want to able to stop the sound while it's playing and Pause, but it can't. The stop button event triggers after it finished.

I Tried to you use WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer and here the stop and pause are working, but the sounds play all at the same time and i created a thread to sleep between the sounds, but the challenge is the duration of the sound is not the same so it can start while other is still playing if it's too long.

```
private SoundPlayer myPlayer;

myPlayer = new SoundPlayer();

    public void PlaySound()
    {

        int PageNo = Convert.ToInt16(cboPage.SelectedItem);
        int lineNumber = 0;
        int fromLetter = 0;
        int toLetter = 0;
        int numberOfLoop = 0;
        int numberOfRepeat = 0;

        try
        {
            numberOfRepeat = Convert.ToInt32(nudRepeat.Value);
            while (numberOfRepeat > 0)
            {

                if (cboLine.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    cboLine.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(cboLine.SelectedItem); }));
                }
                if (cboLetterFrom.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    cboLetterFrom.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { fromLetter = Convert.ToInt32(cboLetterFrom.SelectedItem); }));
                }
                if (cboLetterTo.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    cboLetterTo.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { toLetter = Convert.ToInt32(cboLetterTo.SelectedItem); }));
                }

                numberOfLoop = toLetter - fromLetter + 1;

                while (numberOfLoop > 0)
                {
                    myPlayer.SoundLocation = @"C:\Sound\Page " + PageNo.ToString() + "\\Line " + lineNumber.ToString() + "\\Lesson " + fromLetter + ".wav";
                    myPlayer.PlaySync();

                    fromLetter += 1;
                    numberOfLoop -= 1;
                }
                numberOfRepeat -= 1;

            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fnfe.Message.ToString(), "Audio file not found");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ioe.Message.ToString(), "Invalid wav format");
        }       



    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myPlayer.Stop();                      
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Looked at what happens when you press your stop-button? Events are usually asynchronous, but when your play-method is not aware of that, you can't interrupt it. Maybe mutex or a flag will help?

Comment: The stop button freeze up until its finished I can't click it

Comment: When are you starting `PlaySound`? Do you start it in an event?

Comment: Yes I click on the button that calls that method

Comment: You'd actually need to start a thread, because your button will block, because the method finishes after all of your sounds have played.

Comment: Thanks bash.d I decide to stick with WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer since stop and pause worked there and the only issue was playing multiple audio files in a sequence. I loaded all my audio file in a playlist instead of using a thread.